# How would you end the chain in jquery, then execute your function, but all while inside a chain function

Tags: jquery, dialog, position, modal-dialog

I know this is a weird question in words, so basically I am saying the following. I have this:

```
$("#dialog-areyousuremodal").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 120,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            // more stuff coming soon
            },
        "No": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
}).end().centerFixed();

<div class="hidden" id="dialog-areyousuremodal" title="Delete Confirmation">
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this row?</p>
</div>
```

And I have created a custom function that extends jquery like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        centerFixed: function () {
            return this.each(function() {
            $(this).end();
            $(this).css({position:"fixed"});
            $(this).css("top", (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + "px");
            $(this).css("left", (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + "px");
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

My goal is to replace .end().centerFixed(); with just .centerFixed();. As you can see I tried putting .end() inside the custom function but that does not work. I'm tried to avoid having to put .end() at the end of the dialog or .centerFixed() on a new line.

Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I'm scratching my head and can't think *why* you'd want to do this. Could you explain why you can't use `end()`, there might be an easier solution?

Comment: If your asking why I need to end the chain before running my function: The reason is because jqueryui's dialog window needs to be created before I alter the css.

Comment: If your asking why do I need it to work without having to type end() or go to a newline it is because my teammates just want it to work that way. (I know, its crazy but hey...I'm out voted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't I'm afraid, when `centerFixed()` is called it has no concept of the chain of functions that it has been called at the end of. All it knows about is `this`, which is whatever object is returned from the function called in the previous chain method.

Since you're chaining it at the end of a call to `dialog()`, inside `centerFixed` the variable `this` will be whatever object is the result of that call to `dialog()` (which I think is the UI dialog object).

If you want to ensure your code is only run when the dialog is created, the preferred way to do it would be using the plugin's [`create` event](http://jqueryui.it/demos/dialog#event-create)